# how to display the keyboard that I have created, instead of the default, in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I created this app that generates a table of EditText.
This is the part of code in which septal parameters of layouts.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setContentView(R.layout.seconda);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
N = extras.getInt("dim_matrice");//dimensione della matrice
setKeys();
values = new EditText[N][N];
salvatore = new EditText[N*N];

FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
HorizontalScrollView HSC = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
HSC.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
frameLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lavagna);        
ScrollView VSC = new ScrollView(this);
VSC.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  


for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
tableRow = new TableRow(this); 
tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
values[i][j] = new EditText(this);
values[i][j].setHint(i1 + "   " + j1);
values[i][j].setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
salvatore[sal] = valore[i][j];
tableRow.addView(valore[i][j]);
j1++;
if (j1 == (N+1)){
j1 = 1;
}
sal++;
}

tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

i1++;
if (i1 == (N+1)){
i1 = 1;
}

}

for (i=0;i<N*N;i++){
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
               Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(salvatore[i].getWindowToken(), 0);
salvatore[i].setInputType(0);
salvatore[i].setOnTouchListener(this);
salvatore[i].setOnClickListener(this);
hideDefaultKeyboard();
enableKeyboard();

}


VSC.addView(tableLayout);
HSC.addView(VSC);
frameLayout.addView(HSC);
setContentView(frameLayout);
```

This code displays the EditText table centered on the screen.
This app off the default keyboard to activate the mine that I created separately.
This is the code where I include my keyboard in a relativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/xK1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

<include android:id="@+id/xKeyBoard" layout="@layout/keyboard"></include>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like the display of my keyboard was identical to the default.
So I would like to include it properly in layout-law.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the OnTouchListener for your EditText to show your keyboard instead of the default keyboard.  Make sure you return true in your OnTouchListener to consume the touch event before the EditText pops the keyboard up itself.

If you want to make a custom keyboard that mimics the default keyboard, I suggest you take a look at some of the code/layouts in [Android itself](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java).

Comment: My problem is not to enable my custom keyboard, but  insert this keyboard in framelayout in my app